# How to convert JSON to rich HTML with relevant tags

Tags: php, html, json, wysiwyg, quill

I'm working with a charity who need their own specific CMS to post blogs. I have set up QuillJS which works well and output JSON.

How do I convert JSON data back to HTML with the relevant tags? I need the HTML tags to be shown too such as '`<p>Hello</p>`'. I can get the JSON data via php mysql but don't know how to show the tags.

For example how to I convert the following

```
JSON

{
   "time" : 1589493865899,
   "blocks" : [
       {
           "type" : "header",
           "data" : {
               "text" : "Editor.js",
               "level" : 2
           }
       },
       {
           "type" : "paragraph",
           "data" : {
               "text" : "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this page you can see it in action — try to edit this text."
           }
       }
   ],
   "version" : "2.17.0"
}
```

To

```
HTML

<html>
<h2>EditorJS</h2>
<p>Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this page you can see it in action — try to edit this text.</p>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: presumably you need to read the "type" value from each item, and decide what kind of HTML element that is, and then echo the tags for it. TBH it's a bit unclear where you're stuck. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: @ADyson really sorry if it isn't clear. I don't know where to begin and can't find any good info so don't even know if it is possible. Would you be kind enough to give me an example please?

Comment: Yes it's certainly possible. First you need to parse the JSON into a PHP object so you can work with it. Have you even got that far?

Comment: @ADyson I have got the above JSON in MYSQL and stored it in a PHP variable but that is as far as i've got

Comment: ok well next you need to loop the through the "blocks" property of the variable. Do you know how to access a property of an object (or associative array, depending how you decoded it) in PHP? Do you know how to write a foreach loop?

Comment: @ADyson I've used basic foreach statements before but not for JSON. Would you mind demonstrating both?

Comment: There's no difference. The fact the data came from JSON originally is irrelevant. Remember - JSON is a text format. Once you have decoded it using json_decode, and placed it into a PHP object, then you can use it just like any other PHP object. Same as if it came from XML, or CSV data, or some database columns, or some other made-up storage format.

Comment: @ADyson fab, understood - thank you so much for taking the time so far! So after decoding it, how would I use php to construct a `'<h2>'` tag from 
```"type" : "header",
           "data" : {
               "text" : "Editor.js",
               "level" : 2```

Comment: Well like I said earlier, you need to read the value in the "type" field. If it says "header", then echo `<h2>`. Then echo the contents of "text" (from within "data"). Then echo `</h2>` to close the tag. I'm not sure what the "level" property is supposed to represent. (And, per your sample data, if the "type" said "paragraph" then you'd echo `<p>` and `</p>` instead at the start and end. It's just a case of having a list of possible values for type, and then knowing what HTML tag that corresponds to.)

Comment: @ADyson that makes perfect sense. Would you mind demonstrating exactly how to read the "type" field using a foreach loop? I'd be most appreciative after struggling!

Comment: well please show me what you've written so far in terms of fetching the JSON, decoding it and assigning it to a variable, and your attempt at writing a loop to go through the "blocks" array. Then I can at least put my example in the correct context.

Comment: Fetching & Decoding JSON

```$jsonData = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}
$json = json_decode($jsonData);
echo stripslashes($json);
}
```

Comment: And i'm really struggling with the foreach loop

Comment: that code shouldn't even work. json_decode can't accept an array as input. It doesn't make sense. You should be seeing a warning message something like this: `Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df7ad86f2195213c2ee67a053576e183571fe5c6 .  What is in the rows of your database table, exactly? How many rows does your query output? What does `echo stripslashes($json);` output?

Comment: @ADyson i had it working and have got myself in a muddle. The data in the databse is the JSON code in the question

Comment: show me the working version, then...

Comment: "The data in the databse is the JSON code in the question "....all in one column of one row, I assume you mean? not in multiple rows?

Comment: All in one column of one row yep.

Ok so pulled JSON from MYSQL ok.

Then `$data = json_decode($json);`

Then something like

```foreach ($data as $tag) {
    echo $tag, "\n";
}```

Comment: With that loop you're looping through the properties of the outer object, not through the "blocks" property. To loop through the blocks property you have to ...guess what: reference the "blocks" property! `foreach ($data->blocks as $block)`. Honestly it's not rocket science! Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57f49cb5843b8cb5055d20c2cdef5b3a86d69892

Comment: I wonder if you need to take some basic lessons in object manipulation in PHP, otherwise you're going to seriously struggle to do anything useful with data. e.g. see https://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Comment: @ADyson great - sorry if i'm being stupid and i really apprecaite your help. So now we can get the "type" is it just a case of writing if statements for if "type" is "header" and "level" is "2" and then output <h2>{{data}}</h2>... would you mind starting me off with how to do this?

Comment: I will absolutely take some lessons, i am just desperate to help out this charity ASAP!

Comment: well let's see if you can work it out. That's the best way to learn (and then be able to add to your code further), rather than me just giving you some code you barely understand. Looking at my demo in my last comment, and knowing what you know now, how do you think you might go about accessing the "type" property from within each `$block` object which is presented to you by the foreach loop? Can you see the pattern of how to access a property, from the existing code?

Comment: I added an answer below, but maybe only take a look if you can't figure it out? P.S. the other answer is ok too, if a little overly verbose (some things are repeated which needn't be repeated, and he added an extra array round the JSON for no obvious reason).

Comment: I'm determined to get there myself and will only use your solution if i really can't get there!

Comment: Can I use an AND statement with case i.e. could it be case "header" AND "level" 3 to output <h3>? –

Comment: Well within the "header" case, you could then have another switch statement to check the "level" property, and make a final decision on the exact tag to use based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete solution. Each step is mentioned in the comments:

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{
   "time" : 1589493865899,
   "blocks" : [
       {
           "type" : "header",
           "data" : {
               "text" : "Editor.js",
               "level" : 2
           }
       },
       {
           "type" : "paragraph",
           "data" : {
               "text" : "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this page you can see it in action — try to edit this text."
           }
       }
   ],
   "version" : "2.17.0"
}';

//decode the JSON
$data = json_decode($jsonData);

//loop through the blocks
foreach ($data->blocks as $block)
{
    $start = "";
    $end = "";

    //detect the element type and set the HTML tag string
    switch ($block->type)
    {
        case "header":
            $start = "<h2>";
            $end = "</h2>";
            break;
        case "paragraph":
            $start = "<p>";
            $end = "</p>";
            break;
    }

    //output the final HTML for that block
    echo $start.$block->data->text.$end;
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab862de1113d8744bc2d9463f7a7df2496491110

Comment: I am really appreciative of your time and patience. I will get some lessons and hopefully not bother you again!

Comment: No problem. Hope you learned something as well as getting a solution. If the answer was helpful please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the answer so it turns green). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So you need to first decode the JSON so php can use it as an array and loop through foreach to display.

```php
$someJSON = '{
    "time" : 1589493865899,
    "blocks" : [
        {
            "type" : "header",
            "data" : {
                "text" : "Editor.js",
                "level" : 2
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "paragraph",
            "data" : {
                "text" : "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this page you can see it in action — try to edit this text."
            }
        }
    ],
    "version" : "2.17.0"
 }';
```

Now we decode and display

```php
$someData = json_decode($someJSON, true);
//--> Create an empty variable to hold the display text... 
$output = null;
//--> Run foreach loop, we can see the associative keys in the array, this gives
//--> us everything we need to pull the data out and display it properly... 
//--> loop through the converted arrays first child 'blocks' and get the values
foreach ($someData['blocks'] as $value) {
        //--> If the 'type' === 'header' wrap value -> ['data'] -> ['text'] in <h2> tag
        if($value['type'] === "header"){
            $output .= '<h2>'.$value['data']['text'].'</h2>';
        }
       //--> If the 'type' === 'paragraph' wrap value -> ['data'] -> ['text'] in <p> tag
        if($value['type'] === "paragraph"){
            $output .= '<p>'.$value['data']['text'].'</p>';
        }
    }
```

In your HTML output the variable within php tags to display the concatenated HTML held within `$output`

```html
    <html>
        <div id="my_id">
            <span class="my_class">
                <?=$output?> or <?php echo $output; ?>
            </span>
        </div>
    </html>
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8fdb5b84af5346d640e92e6788e5c2836b9ad07

Comment: Remember everything you need is located right there in your array... Your associative key and value pairs are there, simply construct your logic to loop and look for specifically nested values within their parent/child levels. `array =  $parent[first_child_key][second_level_child_key][third_level_child_key]`... etc...

Comment: The JSON you're using here isn't the same as what's in the question. Was there a reason for that?

Comment: You're correct Dyson, I corrected the code...

Comment: Thanks again dale! What would be the best way to construct a <h2> tag based on the type being header and the level being 2?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements read up on the basics here for heading tags... Though if you want a simple header, you can wrap it in `<div>Header</div>`  tags and then style it as you like. But in your case I think you want a second level heading tag -> `<h2>content</h2>`